# Python change type of whole list?

Tags: python, list

I would like to do something like this

```
def foo(x,dtype=long):
   return magic_function_changing_listtype_to_dtype(x)
```

i.e. a list full of str to a list full of int

any easy way to do it for nested lists, i.e. change the type [['1'],['2']] -> int

Comment: Do you want to mutate the list or get a new one?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Python 2:

```
map(int, ['1','2','3']) # => [1,2,3]
```

...

```
def foo(l, dtype=long):
    return map(dtype, l)
```

In Python 3, map() returns a map object, so you need to convert it to a list:

```
list(map(int, ['1','2','3'])) # => [1,2,3]
```

...

```
def foo(l, dtype=long):
    return list(map(dtype, l))
```

Comment: any easy way to do it for nested lists, i.e. change the type of [['1'],['2']] -> int

Comment: for that it would be `map(lambda sl: map(int, sl), [['1'],['2']]) =>
[[1], [2]]`.

Comment: that would be `map(foo,[['1'],['2']])`

Comment: Sorry, can you explain this syntax ?
    lambda s1: map(int,s1) ??

Comment: @bios, `foo(lambda s1: map(int, s1))` is another way of spelling `def temp(s1): return map(int, s1)` `foo(temp)`. http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda provides a brief explanation, and gooling "python lambda" will provide more protracted ones.

Answer (score 22):

List comprehensions should do it:

```
a = ['1','2','3']
print [int(s) for s in a]   # [1, 2, 3]]
```

Nested:

```
a = [['1', '2'],['3','4','5']]
print [[int(s) for s in sublist] for sublist in a]   # [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: this is not what I want, since you cannot just change from int to any other dtype you want

Comment: @bios: I figured you would know how to write a function to generalize this.

Comment: @bios Yes, you can. Just replace int with a variable - that variable being the type you want.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a fairly simple recursive function for converting nested lists of any depth:

```
def nested_change(item, func):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return [nested_change(x, func) for x in item]
    return func(item)

>>> nested_change([['1'], ['2']], int)
[[1], [2]]
>>> nested_change([['1'], ['2', ['3', '4']]], int)
[[1], [2, [3, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
str_list = ['1', '2', '3']
int_list = map(int, str_list)
print int_list # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as a comment to the answers here which use `map`. In Python 3 this wouldn't work - something like `map(int, ['1','2','3'])` will not return `[1,2,3]` but a map object. To get the actual list object one needs to do `list(map(int, ['1','2','3']))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def intify(iterable):
    result = []
    for item in iterable:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            result.append(intify(item))
        else:
            result.append(int(item))
    return result
```

works for arbitrarily deeply nested lists:

```
>>> l = ["1", "3", ["3", "4", ["5"], "5"],"6"]
>>> intify(l)
[1, 3, [3, 4, [5], 5], 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a=input()#taking input as string. Like this-10 5 7 1(in one line)
a=a.split()#now splitting at the white space and it becomes ['10','5','7','1']
#split returns a list
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i]=int(a[i]) #now converting each item of the list from string type
print(a)  # to int type and finally print list a
```